# What is 'e. m.' in this sentence?

Tags: abbreviations, technical

What does this abbreviation (e. m.) stand for? It seems to me that e.m. is an abbreviation of 'essential medical'. Is this a technical phrase?

> They evac’d only 27 e.m. plus 1 officer from Maisaka, and 17 e.m. plus 2 officers from Sendai, but the RESCUE departed Japan on Sept 19th, they were loaded with 360 e.m. and 30 officer patients bound for either Guam, Hawaii, or CONUS.

Comment: **Enlisted men** would work here, but it seems very dated.

Comment: To communicate directly with someone who posts a comment under your question use @ before the username, e.g @GlobalCharm if they want they can take up your invite otherwise you can write the answer yourself thanking the user for their help.

Comment: @samhana an officer is a career military person who holds a patent of Sargent or above - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Officer_(armed_forces)

Comment: @GlobalCharm Thank you very much for your quick comment. I've found WHAT'S THE DIFFERENCE? ENLISTED VS. OFFICER. Your comment will be a right answer. If you don't mind, would you put your comment as an answer to my question?

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza - the rank of second lieutenant is the lowest commissioned officer rank, and I am not sure of any army that has a rank spelled "sargent".

Comment: How about *John Singer Sargent* and his army of admirers?  Proof that you can receive any number of commissions and still remain among the Other Ranks.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey oops. Typo. But still, sergeant is an officer. Non-commissioned, but still considered an officer, not enlisted

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza - in English speaking armies, the word 'officer' on its own means a 'commissioned officer' (2/Lt and above). Non-commissioned officers (NCOs) are _not_ 'officers'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey so in the context of the text above, are they considered enlisted men?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression “e.m.” is short for “enlisted men”.

To go by the other terms in the quoted passage, this is an American writing about an American military operation.

The contemporary rank structure in the U.S. Army can be found here:  https://www.army.mil/ranks/

The term “enlisted men” has been superseded by “enlisted soldiers”.

Most people are familiar with the broad difference between a commissioned oficer and an enlisted soldier. There is, however, the intermediate rank of *warrant officer*, which has a long history of its own:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warrant_officer

The different branches of the U.S. military make use of the warrant officer rank in different ways. Some warrant officers are equivalent to commissioned officers, but most of the WO ranks are seen as enlisted soldiers.

Given that the text mentions only officers and enlisted men, there were either no warrant officers present, or they were counted as either officers (possible) or as enlisted men (most likely).

A senior warrant officer is often a highly trained specialist (e.g. an Army helicopter pilot). In a military report identifying the “significance” of the soldiers being evacuated, it would make sense to identify them.